# Can Google´s cloud-monitor cause performance issues?

Tags: varnish, google-cloud-platform

I think i have a Problem with Googles Cloud Monitoring.
It fires apprx. 20 log per Second and my Server has a big performance problem.

I used `varnishlog` and `varnishncsa` to view the logs.

Is there a way to stop the process which is fireing or to deactivate the Cloud Monitoring?

```
   11 Debug        c herding
   11 SessionClose c timeout
   11 StatSess     c 173.245.xxx.xxx 312312 1 1 18 0 0 0 7398 4158
   17 Debug        c herding
   17 Interrupted  c ReqStart
   17 ReqStart     c 173.245.xxx.xxx 50606 123123123123
   17 RxRequest    c GET
   17 RxURL        c /
   17 RxProtocol   c HTTP/1.1
   17 RxHeader     c Host: mydomain.com
   17 RxHeader     c Connection: Keep-Alive
   17 RxHeader     c Accept-Encoding: gzip
   17 RxHeader     c CF-IPCountry: NL
   17 RxHeader     c X-Forwarded-For: 5.153.xxx.xxx
   17 RxHeader     c CF-RAY: 1cffb07cf1df00e2-AMS
   17 RxHeader     c X-Forwarded-Proto: https
   17 RxHeader     c CF-Visitor: {"scheme":"https"}
   17 RxHeader     c Cookie: __cfduid=d3208fd678d1fad8234c234c234c234c2
   17 RxHeader     c Accept: */*
   17 RxHeader     c User-Agent: Stackdriver_terminus_bot(http://www.stackdriver.com)
   17 RxHeader     c CF-Connecting-IP: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
   17 VCL_call     c recv lookup
   17 VCL_call     c hash
   17 Hash         c /
   17 Hash         c mydomain.tld
   17 VCL_return   c hash
   17 Hit          c 1123123123123
   17 VCL_call     c hit deliver
   17 VCL_call     c deliver deliver
   17 TxProtocol   c HTTP/1.1
   17 TxStatus     c 302
   17 TxResponse   c Found
   17 TxHeader     c Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)
   17 TxHeader     c Location: https://mydomain.tld/
   17 TxHeader     c Cache-Control: max-age=3600
   17 TxHeader     c Expires: Wed, 01 Apr 2015 00:03:26 GMT
   17 TxHeader     c Vary: Accept-Encoding
   17 TxHeader     c Content-Encoding: gzip
   17 TxHeader     c Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
   17 TxHeader     c Content-Length: 231
   17 TxHeader     c Accept-Ranges: bytes
   17 TxHeader     c Date: Tue, 31 Mar 2015 23:03:45 GMT
   17 TxHeader     c X-Varnish: 123123123 123123123
   17 TxHeader     c Age: 19
   17 TxHeader     c Via: 1.1 varnish
   17 TxHeader     c Connection: keep-alive
   17 Length       c 231
   17 ReqEnd       c 123123123 1427843025.446457863 1427843025.446561337 0.084021330 0.000043869 0.000059605
```

and

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [31/Mar/2015:22:48:53 +0000] "GET http://mydomain.tld/ HTTP/1.1" 302 231 "-" "Stackdriver_terminus_bot(http://www.stackdriver.com)"
```

All IP´s are xx´ed and i changed my domainname of course..

Answer (score 1):

I hope Cloud Monitoring doesn't cause issue performance but... it's still in beta :)

From [here](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/agent/install-agent) I know that for use Cloud Monitoring you have installed an agent: I think is a daemon and if you are on Debian based you can stop it from classic `/etc/init.d` or simple you can unistall with `apt-get remove stackdriver-agent` command.

Hope this help